# When I changed Azure Cloud Services (extended support) Cscfg file in Portal , RoleEnvironment.Changed not trigger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Recently I updated Azure Cloud Services (classical) to Azure Cloud Service (extend support).
It seems that when I changed configuration section in Azure portal, the new value doesn't get. classical Cloud Services works very well.
Does somebody know the reason?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RoleEnvironmentChangedEventHandle = (sender, e) =>
    {
       RoleEnvironmentChangedEventCore(e);
    };
    RoleEnvironment.Changed += RoleEnvironmentChangedEventHandle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I use Upload Cscfg file instead of change value by save button.